# Alguien me da una manito con este dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Una consulta como agrego este diccionario (fruit_dict) a mi data frame (df), que he creado, lo quiero agregar en forma de columna, y si es posible crear un variable nueva en la cabeza de la columna creada nueva

diccionario

```
fruit_dict = {3: 'apple', 2: 'banana', 6:'mango',  4:'apricot', 1:'kiwi', 8:'orange'}
```

```
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {'Computer':1500,'Monitor':300,'Printer':150,'Desk':250}
df = pd.DataFrame(list(my_dict.items()),columns = ['Products','Prices'])

print (df)
print (type(df))
```

Comment: Buen día, la información que has ingresado no es suficiente, ¿Cómo lo quieres "agregar"? Nuevas filas, Nuevas columnas, con algún tipo de "categoría", etc... ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y aclarar el resultado esperado?

Comment: Muchas gracias, si quisiera agregarle como una columna nueva(el diccionario al dataframe), y con una etiqueta nueva de la columna creada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Primero puedes crear un nuevo `dataframe` para tu diccionario de frutas

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(fruit_dict.values()), columns = ['Fruits'])
```

Luego puedes utilizar el método `pd.concat()` para "concatenar" los dos `dataframe`, la documentación completa de `concat()` está [aquí](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

El método `concat()` por defecto concatena filas, pero tiene un argumento `axis` que permite configurar el eje donde se van a concatenar (0 = filas, 1 = columnas)

Por lo que puedes concatenar el `dataframe` de frutas (`df2`) con el que ya tienes hecho (`df`) de la siguiente forma

```
pd.concat([df, df2], axis = 1)
```

El resultado es este:

```
    Products    Prices  Fruits
0   Computer    1500.0  apple
1   Monitor     300.0   banana
2   Printer     150.0   mango
3   Desk        250.0   apricot
4   NaN         NaN     kiwi
5   NaN         NaN     orange
```

Es importante mencionar que como tu diccionario de frutas tiene más elementos (Que se convierten en filas) que el `dataframe` que ya tenías (`df`) entonces se agregan nuevas filas al concatenar los dos `dataframes` y por eso aparecen las filas 4 y 5 con valor "NaN" (Del inglés, Not a Number) en las columnas "Products" y "Prices"